# Align components in web page header

Tags: html, css

I want to align this html code as web page header:

```
<div>
<h1>Web_site_title</h1>

                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Preferences"></h:commandLink>
                </h:form>

                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{language.language}" onchange="submit()">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="bg" itemLabel="Български" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Logout"></h:commandLink>
                </h:form>
</div>
```

I want to get this visual result:

[image]

How I can align the complements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using flex with the settings as shown below. The `auto`  margin-right on the `h1` does the left/right distribution, `align-items: center` is resposible for the vertical centering of all items.

```css
.x {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.x h1 {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <h1>Web_site_title</h1>

  <h:form>A
    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Preferences"></h:commandLink>
  </h:form>

  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{language.language}" onchange="submit()">B
    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="bg" itemLabel="Български" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:form>C
    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Logout"></h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to set unique ID for every component. How I can align the components by id?

Comment: You can use a class on the DIV, for example `<div class="x"> `, use that for the DIV css ( `.x1 { ... }` ) and then use a combined selector for the h1, like `.x h1 { ... }` which only applies to the H1 in the `.x` DIV and doesn't require any class or ID for the H1

Comment: How I can add some space between language selectOneMenu and logout link?

Comment: add `.x > *:last-child {  margin-left: 20px; }  (or whatever value). This adds the margin/distance to the last element inside the `.x` div

Comment: And how I can set space before <h1>?

Comment: add a margin-left

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` with `justify-content: flex-end` to push the elements to the right and `align-items: center` to vertically align them. Then use `margin-right: auto` on the `h1` to push it to the left.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h1>Web_site_title</h1>

  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Preferences"></h:commandLink>form
  </h:form>

  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{language.language}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="bg" itemLabel="Български" />select
  </h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{logoutController.logout}" value="Logout"></h:commandLink>form
  </h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to set unique ID for every component. How I can align the components by id?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you're welcome :) What do you mean align components by id? If you give your `h`, `h:form`, `h:selectOneMenu` an ID, the code would be exactly the same but you would apply the margin to the `id` you assign to the `h1` instead of the `h1`.

Comment: I have many div layers and many h1 components. How I can apply the css code only to the listed components?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you need to share the actual structure, otherwise I'm just guessing. Share an example of that markup and tell me which elements you want this applied to and which elements you don't

Comment: @PeterPenzov not sure what you're asking for. Updated my answer - like that?

Comment: One additional question: How I can add some space between language selectOneMenu and logout link?